# Android app crashes after generating signed apk

Tags: android

UPDATE:
When I delete app storage, it starts to work. I don´t understand...

When I generate a signed APK for my project and I install it to my phone, app crashes. 
**When I debug the app, it works correctly.**

I use Android Studio 3 and I disabled instant run.

Using logcat, I get the following exception:

```
2019-01-15 19:19:30.594 7317-7317/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: me.agomezgz.bng.programa, PID: 7317
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.agomezgz.bng.programa/me.agomezgz.bng.programa.SplashActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: comentario (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):
```

Comment: the problem is in your database handler class . probably you change database code and when your app want to query in your database can not find `comentario` table. post your database class code to help you

Comment: Nope, DB code hasn´t been changed

Comment: post your databas handler class `onCreate` method

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE comentario(" +
                    "_id integer not null primary key," +
                    "nome text not null," +
                    "correo text not null," +
                    "texto text not null," +
                    "idLoc integer not null);");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UPDATE: When I delete app storage, it starts to work. I don´t understand...

You had an earlier version of the database file around that did not have that table. Clearing app storage removed the database file and forced sqlite helper `onCreate()` to run again.

See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Why it worked in debug is that the debug package is another application id and has a separate private directory where the database files are stored. That database file did not have this problem.

Comment: Ok, this problem is fixed. Now it doesn´t sync data with webservice... I´ll try debug mode and see what´s going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it complains about `no such table: comentario` ...which means that table `comentario` had not been previously created - and that the stack-trace is just a follow-up error. see the build output for the ProGuard warnings (or even add them to the question); there might something obfuscated, which should not have been obfuscated. the code of the database class is completely irrelevant (simply because it works, while not being obfuscated); only the build-log matters. adding `-verbose` into the ProGuard configuration might help to obtain some more details.

Comment: @AlfredoDavidGómezSanmartin this is highly unlikely when using ProGuard with the `-verbose` switch... most likely it displays hundreds to thousands of warnings in `release` mode, depending on the size of the code-base, after the line `ProGuard, version 6.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

change your database onCreate method to this :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comentario(_id integer,
nome text not null,
correo text not null,
texto text not null,
idLoc integer not null, primary key (_id));");
```

Comment: Nope, same problem